# Get dates between 2 dates with equal intervals

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 dates `01/04/2017` and `30/04/2017`. I want all the dates between these 2 dates with 7 days interval.

```
Expected Output : 
01/04/2017
08/04/2017
15/04/2017
22/04/2017
29/04/2017
```

Please help!!

Comment: You should probably create a `week` table, with `start_date` attribute when the week starts. You can google for `calendar table` for examples.

Comment: So the end date is "irrelevant" in that it only determines when to stop adding 7 days? What should the output be if the end date *exactly* matches one of the generated dates? E.g. if the end date had been given as `29/04/2017`, would `29/04/2017` have been included in the output?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever... Yes, if the end date matches with last generated date, it will be included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
    @EndDate        DATETIME

SELECT @StartDate = '2017-04-01',
    @EndDate = '2017-04-30'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, number*7, @StartDate)
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE type='P'
    AND  @EndDate >= DATEADD(DAY, number*7, @StartDate)
```

Comment: avoid doing `type = 'P'` to have a numbers table with the numbers from 1-2047.  This is, IMO, a bad practice. Undocumented system tables can be changed by Microsoft without warning, so you should avoid using them.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use a [Calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/). Then return the results from there using the modulus to get the 7th rows:

```
WITH Dates AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date]) AS RN
    FROM DateTable
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '20170401' AND '20170430')
SELECT *
FROM Dates
WHERE (RN - 1) % 7 = 0;
```

I've used this solution, as from your post you imply that you might supply any date range, and that the 1st day may not necessarily be a Monday (or other specific day).

Comment: Yes..start date and end date can be any date.It is not necessarily Monday.

Comment: But this solution works only if I'm storing the data in a table. So what if my dates are just random and I don't have a table? then this won't work

Comment: That's why I linked you to the calendar table. They're extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @STRT DATETIME='04/01/2017',@END DATETIME ='04/30/2017'
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        MyDate = CAST(@STRT AS DATETIME)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        MyDate = CAST(MyDate AS DATETIME)+7
        FROM CTE
            WHERE CAST(MyDate AS DATETIME)+7 < CAST(@END AS DATETIME)
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
```

result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @StartDate DATE=CONVERT(DATE,'01/04/2017',104),@EndDate DATE=CONVERT(DATE,'01/12/2017',104)
Declare @String NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

WHILE (@StartDate<=@EndDate AND DATEDIFF(wk,@StartDate,@EndDate)>=0)
BEGIN

SET @String=@String+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),@StartDate)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)

SET @StartDate=DATEADD(d,7,@StartDate)

END
PRINT  @String
GO
```